# Visual Studio 2019 Error - Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, visual-studio-2019

I have some trouble with running my project. When I try to run, the following error appears:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Dapper,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Context:

I have a Class Library X and a Web Application Y which have dependencies on X. When I try to run my API project, it throws the above error.
BUT, when my colleagues try to run the same API project, it works fine (no errors, and in /bin folder, it loads all the .dll libraries..)

I did those approaches:

- Restart Visual Studio, clean and build a solution
- Remove the class library references and add it again
- Tools > Import and Export Settings Wizard > Reset all settings (maybe some setting was not well configured). I also tried to import colleague settings and didn't work either.

I tried various approaches(even in a different machine, but same VS settings) but none of these worked for me.

Visual studio 2019 16.4 Enterprise.

Comment: you will need to install the nuget package for Dapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your solutions but I found the problem:

The project solution has some projects with .net standard 2.0 and some with .net framework 4.8. Somehow, when I run the app, some packages are not loaded correctly and it throws an error.

That line below solved my problem:

```
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
```

Put it in all .net framework 4.8 projects on first  XML tag.

Thank your for all.

Regards.

Comment: Where did you added RestoreProjectStyle tag?

Comment: Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#using-packagereference-for-a-project-with-no-package-dependencies

Answer (score 3):

I'd also try:

1) Deleting your bin and obj folders in your solution before a rebuild.

2) Check that you've not got multiple versions of the same package across the solution (right click on solution in solution explorer -> manage nuget packages for solution).

3) Check that the properties of the reference (right click in solution explorer on the reference in question) shows a path to the package that you'd expect relative to the solution (eg not in mydocuments/nuget packages or something!).

4) Try a fresh clone of the repo (this should in effect replicate your co-workers' set up) and see if the problem still exists then.

I suppose another cause could be that your coworkers have a locally installed package / dll that they're happily referencing without realising, but you don't have?

Answer (score 0):

When you copy a project from someone or another system, you need to download and install all components. normally VS will give you the option to "restore packages" when you load a newly imported from git but not sure if it does when you open an existing solution from a different system.

Right Click your project, Manage Nuget Packages
Browse -> Search for Dapper. Install

In the error you receieve, it tells you what version of the package should be installed as well. Installing a significantly different version might cause other unexpected errors.

Comment: The problem isn't restore packages (also I tried to restore the packages). Dapper is an example only. In this scenario, Dapper is installed on Class Library X, but when I build the solution, in /bin folder there is no dapper.dll or any reference to this package.

Comment: Remove the reference... uninstall and re-install package

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same Dapper error message today when referencing a .Net Standard 2.1 class library in a .Net Core 3.1 WinForm app. My resolution was to double-click the class library name in Solution Explorer to open the .csproj file, and then add a CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies tag to the PropertyGroup tag and setting it to true.

[image]