# VS Test Explorer requests older version of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions than is installed

Tags: .net, mstest, visual-studio-2022, csla

I've got a Test project that has the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions NuGet package with version 3.1.9 which is the minimum requirement version of the CSLA.NET NuGet package that I've also got installed.
For some reason when I run a test in the Test Explorer it looks for an older version of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (v 3.1.0).
The project is question is using .NET Framework 4.8.1.
I'm a bit puzzled as to what could be the issue.

- I tried to upgrade the installed version to v3.1.32 but then the test seems to look for version 3.1.9.
- I've tried to remove the direct reference to Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions in the test project (it's used in the project being tested), but with the same result.
- I've tried to do Clean + Rebuild.
- I've tried to delete the bin and obj folders in the test project.
- I've upgraded to the latest VS 2022 build (17.5.3) with the same result.

Looking at the bin\Debug folder I can see the correct version as installed in the project.

Comment: I've tried the solution mentioned in this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215005/visual-studio-2019-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-depende) as we also have a mix of projects in v4.8 and .netstandard but without success.
Added this line to v4.8 projects: "**<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>"**

Answer (score 2):

This seems related to the package CSLA.NET that I'm using and the version 5.5.x.
Found the "solution" in their issues on GitHub.
[The issue](https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/issues/2409)
The "solution" is to add binding redirects to app.config.